# In Java, what is the right way to close variables in a method that throws exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

In Java, I often close variables in a `finally` block, like so:

```
public void someMethod(){
  InputStream inStream = null;
  PreparedStatement pStatement = null;

  try{ do something here }
  catch(Exception ex){ do something here }
  finally{
    try{ if (inStream != null) inStream.close(); } catch(Exception ex){/* do nothing */}
    try{ if (pStatement != null) pStatement.close(); } catch(Exception ex){/* do nothing */}
  }
}
```

I am wondering, if the method says it throws an exception, is there a place like a "finally" that I can close the method's variables?
For example:

```
public void anotherMethod() throws SQLException {
  // This method doesn't need a try/catch because the method throws an exception.
  InputStream inStream = null;
  PreparedStatement pStatement = null;

  // Where can I ensure these variables are closed?
  // I would prefer not to have them be global variables.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way would actually be to use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct that was introduced in Java 7.

```
public void anotherMethod() throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(...)) {
        // do things with st
    }
}
```

This ensures that whatever happens in the `try` block (executed successfully or ends with an exception), the resources will be closed. You don't need to add a `catch` part since the method throws the `SQLException`, and more importantly, you don't need to add a `finally` clause: all opened resources are guaranteed to be closed after that statement.